# Can one have a relationship with a deceased rebbe?

Tags: chassidic-rebbe, afterlife

Shalom fam,

Longtime fan of this forum, but this is the first time I’ve ever posted.

Anyhow, is one able to have a relationship with a deceased rebbe?  Meaning, can one learn Torah from a deceased rebbe through the texts or even videos they have left behind?

I ask because a core aspect of Judaism is the talmid-moreh relationship.  But some groups pledge their allegiance to rebbes who are no longer around b’guf.  Is that allowed?

Thanks,
Jesse

Comment: Hi @JesseSandowitz - welcome to Mi Yodeya we hope you stick around. Feel free to learn more and take a tour here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It's a great first question - is there a reason why you would think you couldn't learn from them? Surely that their legacy. Perhaps you can develop your question a bit to make it more focused

Comment: Shalom Jesse! I see no reason why not personally. Breslev haven't had an official living Rebbe since Rebbe Nachman (זיע״א), but no Breslover would say they can't learn from him of course. For me, when I'm reading through their texts and studying their teachings, dead Rebbe's almost come to life in a way. Whether they lived 50 years ago or a hundred, if their words still speak to you I'd say you can most definitely have a relationship with them. That's just my thoughts anyway. I hope you have a peaceful and blessed Shabbat!

Comment: what would the scope of the relationship be? I learn from Moshe Rabbeinu, and Rashi and a bunch of other rabbis. I ask them questions and look for their answers and others' answers to similar questions. I watch as they argue with other rabbis.

Comment: (Can someone grab the relevant quote from the end of Halakhic Mind? @Alex?)

Comment: Hey jesse, hows it going? You're implying the mishna in avos says your rabbi has to be alive? Doesn't say that. You could learn anything from anyone dead or alive. In fact (G'Yvms says) when you learn torah of the deceased they turn in their graves (a good thing).

Comment: Ben Zoma said:Who is wise? He who learns from every man. [Avot 4:4]

Comment: The Rambam says that the Ri Migash is his primary Rebbe, despite the fact that the Ri Migash passed away when he was a child.

Comment: Hi Jesse, I think it's not only allowed but encouraged some.

Comment: The gemoro says one has to 'see' his rebbe to really be able to learn properly from him. One said since he only saw the back it wasnt good enough.

Comment: I might see a general problem if one believes that his dead rebbe is still alive and is, say, physically teaching in the room. But, think of it - all the rabbis mentioned in the Talmud and numerous other works are all dead. Thousands of people study these texts daily. If we didn't *Daf Yomi*, for example, would be impossible.